# Dropdown in html

Tags: html

I have the following code which creates a text box to enter a value that posts the result to another website.

```
<div class="input">
    <label for="sender" class="required">Sender</label>
    <input type="text" name="sender" value="">
</div>
```

How can I turn this into a dropdown selection so that the value will still post the result to the other website?

I tried to use the select tag but I could not get it to post.

Comment: you said that you tried a select tag - update the code in the question to what you tried

Comment: You definitely need to use the Select tag. You say you couldn't get it to post? Re-do you question with the select tag and why it isn't posting and all code involved

Comment: Expression engine is what I am working on and this website suggested the stackexchange tag based on the previous tags. But I removed them,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this website, it uses the post method.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This sends the dropdown value to the php page.
Check out the link I posted, hope it helps.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: So what was your problem with your `<select>` you've tried?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I'm new to programming so there has been a lot of trial and error and I don't have the original code anymore.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so multiple selections can be made at once?

Comment: @PeterD You could use a checkbox instead of a droodown if you want.

Comment: I was able to use select multiple instead

Comment: @PeterD I find that interesting can you post a jsfiddle link to that

Comment: Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/qj46gLhe/  You have to hold ctrl when making multiple selections

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `<select>` tag like this.

```html
<form action="/action.php" method="POST">
  <div class="input">
    <label for="sender" class="required">Sender</label>
    <select name="sender">
      <option>Anna</option> <!-- if no value is set, Anna will be used in this case -->
      <option value="another value">Peter</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

But if you still want to keep the ability to enter text and have a dropdown, you can combine a `input` field with a `datalist`

```html
<form action="/action.php" method="POST">
  <div class="input">
    <label for="sender" class="required">Sender</label>
    <input type="text" name="sender" list="senderNames" />
    <datalist id="senderNames">
      <option>Anna</option>
      <option>Peter</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although a `select` would be the obvious answer, you can also try to use HTML5's `datalist` element.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Here's a working example:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="some-id" placeholder="Select a greeting" name="hello" list="my-data-list">
  <datalist id="my-data-list">
    <option value="Hello World">
    <option value="Hello Friend">
  </datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

It's well supported by browsers too: http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="input">
 <!-- the action attribute simple means page link where you want to Post the data to  -->
          <form action="link_of_another_website" method="POST">

            <select name="sender" required >
             <!-- make the firs one empty -->
            <option></option>
            <!-- list of sender names -->
            <option value="Ama">Ama</option>
            <option value="Kofi">Kofi</option>
            <option value="Dawud">Dawud</option>
             <!-- list of sender names -->
            </select>

            <br/>
            <br/>
          <input type="submit">

           </form>
        </div>
```